# Возможно ли скомпилировать bash в apk?

Tags: android, bash, apk, sh

Возможно ли скомпилировать bash в apk? Или есть программы для запуска bash скриптов на Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скомпилировать - нет. APK не так прост. А запустить - можно. Например с помощью "[Terminal Emulator for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm)".

Comment: стоит упомянуть и полноценный [эмулятор операционной системы gnu](https://termux.com/)

Comment: @aleksandr barakin одна и та же суть. Android - полноценная ОС. Методов запустить шел много